# Adding space between input

Tags: css, html

I was trying to make a application form. I have six input's in my form. But the input's are close together.

https://gyazo.com/939f90c739d538ab53e14bb4e1402b1f

I'd like to add to add some space between my inputs. I searched a answer on stackoverflow, but I couldn't use that because they used a `textarea`

My codes: (I used bootstrap classes)

```html
<div class="center_div">
  <form class="contact-form" id="solliform" role="form" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email (nodig voor uitslag)">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="naam" name="naam" placeholder="Habbonaam">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="leeftijd" name="leeftijd" placeholder="Uw leeftijd">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rang" name="rang" placeholder="Voor welke rang solliciteert u">
    <div class="text-center">
      <button class="btn btn-main btn-lg" type="submit button" id="send" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#sollipop">Verzenden</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use CSS to add space like so:

```
input{
    display: block;
    margin-top:20px;
}

button{
  margin-top:20px;
}
```

Comment: Margin-top causes the submit button to look wonky

Answer (score 0):

Use Margin Classes Available in Bootstrap.
In Your Html Code Add.

```
<input type="email" class="form-control m-1" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email (nodig voor uitslag)">
```

For More Details visit

[Bootstrap - Margin and Padding](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/utilities-for-layout/#margin-and-padding)